# Get the ID of every image in a container

Tags: jquery, each

I have a list of images in a container (`this.element`) and I wish to get the ID of each of these images.

I have the below, but I'm being told that `value.attr is not a function`.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
var images = this.element.find('img');
$.each(images, function(index, value){
    console.log(value.attr(id));
});
```

An example of my HTML -

```
<div id="front-page-gallery" class="image-gallery"> <!-- This is `this.element` above -->
    <img id="image-7293" class="active" title="Home Page 1" src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Home-Page-1.jpg">
    <img id="image-7294" title="Home Page 2" src="http://test.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Home-Page-2.jpg">
    <img id="image-7295" title="Home Page 3" src="http://test.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Home-Page-3.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: `console.log(this.id);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('img').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the id of the element simply using `this.id`

```
var images = this.element.find('img');
$.each(images, function(){
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use:

```
$.each(images, function(index, value){
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

or:

```
$.each(images, function(index, value){
    console.log($(value).attr('id'));
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/a44LS/)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use `(index, value)` ... this one also works: http://jsfiddle.net/AR3sm/2/

```
$.each(images, function(index, value){
    alert($(value).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly part of your html seems to be commented.

secondly assuming that by this.element you are referring to div tag the jquery code should be

```
$.each(images, function(index, value){
    console.log($(value).attr("id"));
});
```

see demo on http://jsfiddle.net/WEr22/1/